# Configure a default host for routes in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony4

So far my Symfony app was hosting a single domain. Now, I need to host a few pages on another domain. For business reasons, this must appear as a separate domain to the user, even though it actually belongs to the same app.

Say my app is hosted on `example1.com`.
I need to host some pages on `example2.com`.

So I created a new controller:

```php
class NewsletterController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/unsubscribe", name="newsletter_unsubscribe", host="example2.com")
     */
    public function unsubscribe(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('newsletter/unsubscribe.html.twig');
    }
}
```

This works fine; the page is served correctly, and the `/unsubscribe` path in only routed when requested on `example2.com`. On `example1.com`, it returns a `404` as expected.

The issue is, now all routes intended to be matched on the main domain `example1.com`, are also matched on `example2.com`, which is not what I want.

Of course, I could change all other `@Route` annotations to include `host="example1.com"`, but this is cumbersome and prone to mistakes in the future.

**Is there a way to require a `host` for all routes by default, unless overridden in the `@Route` annotation?**

Comment: DId you try to set onKernelRequest Listener to "parse" all requests before routing ?

Comment: @bZezzz No, I was hoping there was a simple configuration value for this purpose!

Comment: Tryed @Route before your "class" not before your function and separate your contoller for each domain ?

Comment: @bZezzz Setting up `@Route` above each controller class would work, and would be a bit better than on each controller method, I agree. Still, if there was a global configuration setting, I'd be more comfortable with it!

Comment: I will search for it ;)

Comment: With ReflectionClass you can't parse annotations to check if contains "host" ? Maybe a solution

Comment: @bZezzz I'd know how to *hack* it, but I will definitively **not** ;-)

Comment: Annotations can be parsed easily and without any "hack" ;) So good luck dude

Comment: @bZezzz Until someone comes up with a better solution, I'll use the `@Route` parameter on each controller *class*. If you wish to write an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a final solution but it can help...

You can set the **@Route** annotation to each controller class and separate your controllers for each domain...

```php
/**
 * @Route(host="example2.com")
 */
class NewsletterController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/unsubscribe", name="newsletter_unsubscribe")
     */
    public function unsubscribe(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('newsletter/unsubscribe.html.twig');
    }
}
```

We will find a better solution soon :)

Comment: Actually it's better than that: if you define the `@Route` annotation on both the class and the method, the annotations get merged, so you can define the `host` at class level, and the rest at method level. This way you can keep your controllers organized by having several methods inside them. I edited your answer to reflect this!

Answer (score 1):

You could define default host in annotation.yaml

```php
//config\routes\annotations.yaml

controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    host: mydomain.com
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, you can't override `host` at the annotation level anymore (symfony 6).